# How do I access this built-in SEDE functionality to run multi-site queries?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, data-explorer

Queries in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) are usually run over one database, i.e. a single Stack Exchange site. It *is* possible to do a multi-site query by fully qualifying tables (including the database name), and there are some tricks like building up a dynamic SQL string which fills a temporary table when executed. There are countless examples/templates, [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1609644/self-answers-you-didnt-accept) is one of my latest versions which stands on the shoulders of several other giants.

This morning I was checking SEDE's source code and stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/QueryRunner.cs#L85):

```
private static QueryResults GetMultiSiteResults(ParsedQuery parsedQuery, User currentUser, AsyncQueryRunner.AsyncResult result = null)
{
    var sites = Current.DB.Sites.All();
    if (parsedQuery.TargetSites == TargetSites.AllNonMetaSites)
    { 
        sites = sites.Where(s => !s.Url.Contains("meta.")).ToList();
    }
    else if (parsedQuery.TargetSites == TargetSites.AllMetaSites)
    {
        sites = sites.Where(s => s.Url.Contains("meta.")).ToList();
    }
    else if (parsedQuery.TargetSites == TargetSites.AllNonMetaSitesButSO)
    {
        sites = sites.Where(s => !s.Url.Contains("meta.") && !s.Url.Contains("stackoverflow.")).ToList();
    }
    else if (parsedQuery.TargetSites == TargetSites.AllMetaSitesButMSE)
    {
        sites = sites.Where(s => s.Url.Contains("meta.") && s.Url != "http://meta.stackexchange.com").ToList();
    }
```

To my untrained eye, that seems like a built-in functionality for cross-site queries; it even seems to offer some kind of aggregation. It is possible to access this functionality, or is it a remnant of a long-lost feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a lost feature. It is something that can be enabled/disabled per running instance. But it is only enabled on internal-facing instances of it that staff have access to.

The option is [added to the query editing page](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/806706a5f5af3f6a153a5c7089b75c625ca355a1/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Views/Shared/Query.cshtml#L51) when it is enabled.